# object is not converting to numeric after pd.to_numeric

Tags: python, pandas, numeric

I dont understand why my column allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'] is not converting into numeric?

Initially i replaced empty rows with the number 0  but int 0 and floats numbers did not make the column allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'] easily convertible to numeric (got error TypeError: len() of unsized object). Now I left empty rows as they are and forced the floats to convert to numeric but it did not work- allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'] is is still an object. See below

```
allHoldingsFund['ratioBest']

Out[170]: 
100                          
144                          
187         0.520704845814978
264                          
386                          
494                          
597                          
635         2.790492957746479

allHoldingsFund['ratioBest']=pd.to_numeric(allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'], errors='coerce')

Name: ratioBest, Length: 1664, dtype: object
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Idea - are data confidental?

Comment: And what is your pandas version?

Comment: yes data is confidential  .what do you have in mind?    pd.__version__
Out[171]: '0.22.0'

Comment: It's hard to replicate your problem without the data. In a mini example of mine your code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get your problem - values are not scalar, but `numpy.ndarray`s:

```
allHoldingsFund = pd.DataFrame({'ratioBest':[np.array(4.12), '']})
print (allHoldingsFund)
        ratioBest
0      4.12
1
```

Solution is convert to `list` and then to `1d array`:

```
arr = np.array(allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'].tolist())
allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'] = (pd.to_numeric(arr, errors='coerce'))
print (allHoldingsFund)
   ratioBest
0       4.12
1        NaN

print (allHoldingsFund['ratioBest'].dtype)
float64
```

Comment: thanks for continuous help on this.    i get this as error:  TypeError: don't know how to convert scalar number to float

Comment: @SBad - I find problem and added solution.